# 3 page spread in saddle stitch publication - InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, cs6, imposition

I am printing an A5 booklet with 36 pages. I am doing a test print as a saddle stitch booklet. One of the spreads has photographs that span out over 3 pages so it is a fold out part. I have no idea how to imposition this with the additional 3 page spread. I thought somehow I could print the 3 page spread separately on an A3 page but that would mess up the multiples of 4 in the publication if I removed it.

Comment: One thing is to make the logic work so you will be able to print this yourself. Another thing is if it's actually possible to make at the print shop you are using. If you're need to print this commercially you need to get in touch with the print shop! A saddle stitch booklet is normally stitched first and then cut so the folded page must be smaller to not be cut off. Going to work, I can answer this tonight but somebody will probably answer it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy will be to print the booklet without the fold out, then print a replacement spread with the folded page included.

Demonstrated with a 12 page booklet below. The fold out page is “a/b”.

[image]